Error restricted when trying to create module files using shc
(https://i.sstatic.net/0kYQi.jpg)
I have created modules with shc encrypted, but the file inside itself does not work, when i tried to execute manually using 'su -c ROCK' it gives me an error like in the picture. Can anyone help me? I dont have much experience about magisk. I have created one module and it did work with the file encrypted using Bash-Crypt. But when i tried to use shc to encrypr, it give an error like in the picture.
Create magisk module and encrypt it with 'shc -r -f' command
